# negate a javascript regex to match all except ranges

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji, negate

I'm not very good with regex and I could use some help.
I'm trying to match all characters except the ones defined by those ranges (ranges that match most emoji). How would I negate the statement below?

```
var nonEmoji = new RegExp(/[\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]|\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]]*$/, 'i');
```

Comment: Split with the pattern.

Comment: Can you provide more details, please?

Comment: @VictorDragnea I think he means that you can use your current pattern as split sequence with [`split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). This will just leave the parts besides the split sequence and maybe some empty matches that can be filtered later on.

Comment: I mean try `text.split(nonEmoji)`. Or `text.split(nonEmoji).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: I don't want to use split(). Isn't there a way to negate the above (match all, except the ranges)?